# The popup doesn't open once closed, but the audio plays in the background

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, video-streaming, jquery-mobile-popup

I am trying to show a video in a popup, which pops up when clicked on an image. When I try to close the popup the 'X-button' on the top-right corner the popup closes and doesn't open again but the audio plays in the background. The code goes as follows:

```
<script>
    function CreatePopup() {
    //create a div for the popup
    var $popUp = $("<div/>").popup({
    id : "pop1",
    dismissible : false,
    theme : "a",
    overlyaTheme : "a",
    transition : "pop",
    position : "origin"
    });

    //create a title for the popup
    $("<h2/>", {
    text : "Video Feed"
    }).appendTo($popUp);
    $("<a/>", {
    id : "cls",
    href : "#",
    "data-rel" : "back",
    "data-role" : "button",
    "data-theme" : "a",
    "data-icon" : "delete",
    "data-iconpos" : "notext",
    "data-transition" : "flip",
    "class" : "ui-btn-right",
    text : "Close"
    }).appendTo($popUp).bind("click", (function() {
    RemovePopup();
    }));
    $("<iframe/>", {
    id : "ifr",
    src : "media/sap.mp4",
    width : "200px",
    height : "200px"
    }).appendTo($popUp);
    $popUp.popup("open").trigger("create");
    }
    function RemovePopup() {

    //$("#ifr").remove();
        $("#pop1").empty();
    $("#pop1").popup("close");

    }

    $(function() {
        $("#img1").click(function() {
        CreatePopup();
            });
    });
</script>
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="images/supermarket.jpg" style="width: 600; height: 500; float: left; display: inline; margin-left: 200px;">

        <a id="g1c1" href="#pop1" style="position: absolute;top:191px;left:334.28125px;" data-rel="popup" data-inline="true" data-transition="popup" data-mini="true"> <img id="img1" src="images/cctvcam.jpg"> </a>
    </div>

</body>
```

Please help me find a solution out of it.

Comment: $("#pop1").empty();
    $("#pop1").popup("close");$('#ifr').attr('src', $('#ifr').attr('src')); please modify ur RemovePopup() function

Comment: I modified the function. The problem that is occuring now is, the popup doesn't open second time I click on the image. Only the audio is heard.